# What's different between Publisher ID and Mediation ID?

Tags: android, admob

I use AdMob in my android app with the following code, which ID between Publisher ID and Mediation ID should I fill in the ads:adUnitId="*REMOVED*" ?
Thanks!

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="_REMOVED_"
                     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to request Ads from the ad network, you must send your Publisher ID. Mediation ID is used for creating a mediation placement.

Publisher ID is used to request banner ads and interstitials.

For further info, check out this [Difference between Publisher ID and Mediation ID](http://www.webpronews.com/google-explains-admob-publisher-and-mediation-ids-2012-04)

FYI. I'm going to edit your post to remove your publisher id ;)